# React material-ui Menu: how to dynamically fill nested menus?

Tags: dynamic, menu, material-ui

I would like to dynamically fill the 'menuItems' property of a MenuItem (https://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu) from an array of values.
I found several posts about using the map syntax, and indeed I managed to make it work to fill the Menu with MenuItem elements. However I didn't manage to make it work to fill the menuItems array (nested menus).

Any help appreciated, I'm new with react and javascript so it is likely I'm missing something obvious.
Thanks

Here is what I wrote:

```js
class PopupMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { menu: props.menu, key: (props.menu.id + "_menu"), open: false, actions: null};
  }

  
...
  
  async createActionOrMenu(actionOrMenu) {
   if (actionOrMenu[1] == true) {
    // submenu
    let menu = actionOrMenu[0];
    let actionsOrMenus = await window.epic.content(menu);
    return <MenuItem 
     primaryText={label(menu.title)} 
     menuItems={actionsOrMenus.map(this.createActionOrMenu.bind(this))} // the line I have problem with
    />
   } else {
    //action
    let action = actionOrMenu[0];
    return <MenuAction action={action}/>
   }
  }
  
  createActions(actionsOrMenus) {
   if (!actionsOrMenus || actionsOrMenus.length === 0) {
    return;
   }
   return actionsOrMenus.map(this.createActionOrMenu.bind(this)); // the map syntax to dynamically fill elements: works like charm
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FlatButton
    className="menubar_menu"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          label={label(this.state.menu.title)}
    hoverColor="lightgrey"
    primary = {this.state.open}
        />
        <Popover
          open={this.state.open}
          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
          anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom'}}
          targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
          onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
        >      
          <Menu key= {this.state.key+"popup"}>
          {this.createActions(this.state.actions)}
          </Menu>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is the console output: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `menuItems` supplied to `MenuItem`, expected a ReactNode.
    in MenuItem

Comment: It seems that my problem is the async keyword for createActionOrMenu. The function returns a Promise instead of the jsx array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working code:
The first issue I had to fix was my 'async' keyword, see comments.
Then this line works: menuItems={createActions(this.state.actions)}

```js
class MenuAction extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {action: props.action};
 }
 
 render () {
  return (
   <MenuItem primaryText={label(this.state.action.text)}/>
  );
 }
}

function createActionOrMenu(actionOrMenu) {
  if (!actionOrMenu || !actionOrMenu[0]) {
  console.error("invalid action/menu sent to createActionOrMenu");
  return;
 }
  if (actionOrMenu[1] == true) {
   // submenu
   return <SubMenu menu= {actionOrMenu[0]} key = {actionOrMenu[0].id + "_submenu"} />
  } else {
   // action
   return <MenuAction action= {actionOrMenu[0]} key = {actionOrMenu[0].id + "_action"}/>
  }
}

function createActions(actionsOrMenus) {
 if (!actionsOrMenus || actionsOrMenus.length === 0) {
  return;
 }
 return actionsOrMenus.map(createActionOrMenu);
}
  
  

class SubMenu extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { menu: props.menu, actions: []};
 }
 
 UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
   this.init();
 }
  
 async init() {
  let content = await window.epic.currentPage.menuBarSite.content(this.state.menu);
  this.setState({actions: content});  
 } 
   
  render() {
   return <MenuItem 
   primaryText={label(this.state.menu.title)} 
   key={this.state.menu.title}
   menuItems={createActions(this.state.actions)}  // this works
    />
  }
}

class PopupMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {menu: props.menu, actions: [], open: false};
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
   this.init();
  }
  
  async init() {
   let content = await window.epic.currentPage.menuBarSite.content(this.state.menu);
   this.setState({actions: content});  
  }
  
  handleClick = (event) => {
    // This prevents ghost click.
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      open: true,
      anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
    });
  };

  handleRequestClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false,
    });
  };
  

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FlatButton
    className="menubar_menu"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          label={label(this.state.menu.title)}
    hoverColor="lightgrey"
    primary = {this.state.open}
        />
        <Popover
          open={this.state.open}
          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
          anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom'}}
          targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
          onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
        >      
          <Menu key= {this.state.key+"_popup"}>
      {createActions(this.state.actions)}
          </Menu>
        </Popover>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```